# How to group arguments using flag in golang

Tags: go, arguments, command-line-interface

In my use case I am writing a CLI in golang with multiple group of arguments. For example

```
./gocli -test <test-name> -load <no-of-cases>
./gocli -startserver <server-name> -port <port-number>
./gocli -addhost <host-name>
```

CLI is used for different purposes. I could write a check for each flag variable and perform the actions. But is there any best approach to do this? Also I would like to validate the arguments for each group[For example, if any of the arguments missing in a group while others are given, CLI should throw an error]

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: It sounds like you actually want different subcommands, each with their own flag sets, e.g. `./gocli test -name <name> -load <num_cases>`, `./gocli startserver -name <name> -port <port>`, and `./gocli addhost -name <host_name>`.

Comment: Subcommands solved the purpose !!